# Container Type that doesn't corrupt on Encoding Crash

Tags: encoding, video-recording

I've been produce videos on YouTube for a few years. I understand a vast majority of encoding options for x264 (My preferred encoder).

I used to use MPEG-4 containers (.mp4) with my videos, however my system isn't the most powerful and the encoder will sometimes crash mid-encoding, causing the file to be unreadable because of how MPEG-4 file data is organized.

So I switched to using FLV as the container, and remuxing it to MPEG-4 after recording is done. FLV's organization of the data allows the file to be read, even if the file was never completed. I don't understand much about the actual formats, but Id suspect it's an absence of a footer in the format for FLV.

The problem I'm having with FLV, is that when I used MP4, I record with multiple audio tracks, so that I can edit them independently. FLV does not support multiple audio streams.

I'm wondering if there is a container for x264, that's still high quality, allows for multiple audio tracks, and can still be read if encoding crashes.

I am recording with a program called OBS-Studio (OBS Multi-Platform), which allows the following containers for x264: FLV, MP4, MOV, MKV, TS

Are any of those last 3 formats capable of such functionality. I have tried a few days of research and can't find anything regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, TS is capable of doing what you are asking. Weather OBS is, is another question (that I do not know the answer to). mkv MAY be also to as well. But mp4 and mov can not do this.

Comment: OBS is able to use multiple channels with formats that support it. So if TS can, then thanks. So you're saying that TS files would still be readable if the recording program stopped responding?

Comment: TS files are meant for streaming, so don't use global headers.

Comment: Meant to add: so an aborted encode will still play.